# Authorize in API blocks data loading in maui app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, maui

I have a .net maui application which displays the data with the API, however when I want to add the Authorize in the controller for security, in my .net maui app it no longer displays the data

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions
                .ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IActivitiesRepository, ActivitiesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoriesRepository, CategoriesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGroupsRepository, GroupsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IImagesRepository, ImagesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ActivitiesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IActivitiesRepository _activitiesRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ActivitiesController(IActivitiesRepository activitiesRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _activitiesRepository = activitiesRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ActivitiesEntity>> GetActivitiesbyIdAsync(int id)
    {
        ActivitiesEntity activitiesEntity = await _activitiesRepository.FindByIdAsync(id);
        return Ok(activitiesEntity);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>>> GetActivities()
    {
        IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>? activities = await _activitiesRepository.FindAllIncludingAsync(x => x.Images);
        var response = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ActivitiesModel>>(activities);
        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAllActivitiesByUserId/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>>> GetAllActivitiesByUserId(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>? activities = await _activitiesRepository.FindActivitiesByUserIdAsync(id);
        var response = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ActivitiesModel>>(activities);
        return Ok(response);

    }
}
```

I have several controllers and I have the same problem everywhere
I therefore want to add Authorize to secure my API, however, it blocks data loading in the app

Comment: where is the relevant client code?  What specifically is happening - does it timeout, or return an HTTP failure code, or something else?

Comment: I receive a 401 "Unauthorized" error

Comment: I'd guess that there is a problem with your client auth code, but since you haven't shared that with us its impossible to say

Comment: Do you want me to share something?, without authorize the data is loaded

Comment: Yes, I've asked **twice** for you to share the relevant client code.

Comment: Okay, It's done

Comment: in your MAUI app, how do you connect to the API and retrieve data?   That is the code I want to see.

Comment: I added the ViewModel

Comment: Have you debugged the client code to verify the token is getting correctly added to the header?  Are you sure the token is valid?  Have you checked the logs on the server for any useful messages, and/or to verify that the server is receiving the request as expected?

Comment: well for authtoken I added the 2 ways that I do in the example and in the 2 authtoken is null

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your source code and the only thing that could come to my mind is the usage of the async-await pattern which could do the blocking if not used correctly, which doesn't seem the case. However, you should consider the following improvements in the code.

1. You must do : (i.e. replace
   `public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)` with `public async Task`. you can return nothing with the usage of `Task`.
2. Please return the normal `Items` array, as it would be automatically treated as `IEnumerable` for the Task-based return type.

Other than that, I don't see the blockage being caused by the current code until you debug down the call at the lowest deep. Please make sure the caller has complete authorization for all the action methods and token is quite valid and access is being granted to execute the code within the controller method.

Comment: Even when I test the API I receive the 401 error

Comment: That means you have an authorization problem. Your token does not contain the required claims to get into the specific action method for which you trying to access. In this case, it could be the entire controller.  Do one thing : Prepare just sample WebAPI controller and put some methods inside that. Make sure there is no MAUI stuff in your application and try to access the controller action method there.

Comment: See what it does. Does it allow you to login into the endpoints in that case? If not that then in that case., it has nothing to do with MAUI , it would be invalid token problem.

Comment: Yes even when I test with the API I receive the unauthrorize

Comment: Do you mean when there was no MAUI stuff at all? Plain C# .NET Core code, write Test WEB API, and configure whole token generation and validation code

Comment: Please show only that specific code in the post where there is no MAUI and only specific test code which is failing.

Comment: Sure, I only put the api code because that's actually the problem with the error 401